# How to start a program in another Windows Terminal session? (as an Administrator)

Tags: windows, session, terminal-services, runas

Let's say the user `Administrator` is logged in in terminal session `2`. Another user `Boda` is logged in terminal session `3`.

Is it possible to start a program from session `2` in session `3`?

For example, let's say I want to start `calc.exe` in session `3` (in Boda's session). How do I do that? Can it be done with `runas` tool? Any other tool?

Comment: Posted an answer on your duplicate bounty question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28932486/1175077