# How to start java application in non zero session?

Tags: java, windows, command-line, windows-7-x64

Java application (testng tests) is started from command line with a process (user, not system) that is running with Session ID = 0, so java.exe process is also running with Session ID = 0:

```
java -cp "/opt/testng-6.8.jar:bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

As all UI is blocked for this session I've got message displayed:

[image]

Is there any possibility to start it with another Session Id from zero session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a post (see answer by @jpw)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910831/runas-in-another-windows-terminal-session) about usage of `PsExec.exe` to run in different `Session Id`, e.g.:

```
psexec.exe -i 3 cmd.exe
```